# How can I transfer article content from old Joomla 1.5 site to new 2.5 site

Tags: joomla, migration

I have an existing Joomla 1.5 site and am intending to wipe it and install a brand new 2.5 site.  I will pick new plugins, template etc but would like to transfer the basic text / images of the articles on the 1.5 site to the new site.  I am less concerned with categories and tags of those old articles, as they'll probably go in an 'old' category.

I have several file and database backups of the 1.5 site.  Has anyone done anything similar ?  Are the two article db schemas similar enough to just transfer the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While JUpgrade is recommended (and does copy media like images etc) it can often be problematic. We've had much more success with [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609) for full site migrations.

For transferring just the article content you will probably be better served by [J2XMLImporter](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15807) which focuses on the content (ie. articles plus categories, users & weblinks ([all required for articles]). We've used this successfully for sites that don't require anything other than the core content to be moved.

Comment: I couldn't get JUpgrade to work and ended up with J2XMLImporter, which totally fitted what I wanted, as I could edit / tweak the XML file before import.

Answer (score 3):

No, don't copy the tables - that schema has changed quite a bit. You can install the free JUpgrade extension, which will download and install a 2.5 into a subfolder of your website and populate the new DB with your content, categories, users, etc. It can also handle some 3rd party extensions like Community Builder, Virtuemart and Kunena. That's the official method of doing a migration to 2.5.

More info here: http://www.cmsbloke.com/migrating-to-joomla-2-5-step-by-step-tutorial/
and here
http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5

Images and media will need to be copied over manually as these extensions only update the DB.

Make sure your php timeouts aren't too short as some of the steps can take a while & make sure you backup first. ;-)

Comment: as cppl states below SP Upgrade is good also. The cmsbloke link shows how to use both. SP Upgrade is what I usually use unless I need 3rd party extension data translated as well (k2, vm, kunena, etc), but SP is so simple it gets used more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may tranfer your data automatedly. I have imported articles, images, user, internal links and other entities. I was recommended online service cms2cms. it made all this job really fast, i've just pressed some buttons)

wish you luck! 
Take care of your content))